# How to disable xamdatagrid cell editing in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, infragistics

I used xamdatagrid cellupdated event,inside that event i have to disable the specific cell in editing and want to enable it after getting the response of an API call,the problem is when i enable the cell after disabling it,the cursor wont set in the correct position.

```
private async void RenewDataGrid_OnCellUpdated(object sender, CellUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    row.Cells[4].IsEnabled = false;
    await datacontext.CalculateFdtotalAmount();
    row.Cells[4].IsEnabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had similar types of issues with XamDataGrid within a function call. I solved it by processing the statements like the old windows PeekMessage. To do that, try something like:

```
private async void RenewDataGrid_OnCellUpdated(object sender, CellUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    row.Cells[4].IsEnabled = false;
    DoEvents();
    await datacontext.CalculateFdtotalAmount();
    DoEvents();
    row.Cells[4].IsEnabled = true;
}



    public object ExitFrame(object f)
    {
        ((DispatcherFrame)f).Continue = false;
        return null;
    }
    public void DoEvents()
    {
        DispatcherFrame frame = new DispatcherFrame();
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
            new DispatcherOperationCallback(ExitFrame), frame);
        Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
    }
```

Comment: Thank U SteveFerg...I works for me....Great Work...Can you please Explain the logic behind this?

Comment: I have found that some calls are cached. Until you exit a function, it doesn't actually perform the API call immediately. I have also found, especially at initial window loading, that there have been times where I have had to put in a short timer for cellpresenter calls. It was the result of hours and hours of colorful language and head-banging to figure out when there is nothing wrong with the code, it just wouldn't work. I have only found that issue with some Infragistics calls for some reason. Once I made the above changes, I had not had a problem since.